# How to detect paste in text input area if user paste a whole text or string in it?

Tags: javascript

Note : Do not mark this as a duplicate question, sure this is not. But it is related to certain question out there.

There are click event or touch event to detect paste in the text field. But now there is a new trick to paste content in text field using mobile "swift keyboard" android keyboard. Which enables clipboard option to paste the predefined text into any input field. I tried almost every online answers and this clipboard works without detecting any event in the browser.

So help me out to solve this issue, i want to detect this certain clipboard event in the text field and block users from using it.

```
<textarea name="msg" placeholder="Type message here...." class="materialize-textarea" onCopy="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false" onPaste="return false" oncontextmenu="return false" onkeydown="if ((arguments[0] || window.event).ctrlKey) return false"></textarea>
```

Sure this blocks normal paste in desktop or mobile devices. But, it can't detect certain clipboard content paste.

I need a real solution to fix this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of detecting whether a paste event has occurred, you can listen for an `input` event on the `textarea`. Then by keeping track of the previous length of the string in the textbox you can see if the input has changed by more than one character.

See working example below:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const textarea = document.querySelector('.materialize-textarea');
  let prev_val = textarea.value;
  let prev = prev_val.length;

  textarea.addEventListener('input', function() {
    let new_len = this.value.length;
    let dif = new_len - prev;
    if (dif > 1) {
      alert("paste detected!");
      textarea.value = prev_val;
    } else {
      prev = new_len;
    }
    prev_val = this.value;
  });
}
```

```html
<textarea name="msg" placeholder="Type message here...." class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
```

Although, this solution does have its limitations.

Comment: I was also about to answer the same :)

Comment: here you go >> https://www.tamil2friends.com/paste/

not working :( i test the same code you gave me.

Comment: @NickParsons thanks for the real help :) works like a charm.

Comment: @JosephMiller I do have to warn you however, this does have its limitations. For instance, if you try and use the suggested text on the keyboard when typing it won't allow you to do so :/

Comment: @NickParsons dammn, thats something gonna make people mad. Is there any way to detect long sentences? like more than 4 words pasting?

Comment: @NickParsons can't use emoji in the textarea  too :O

Comment: @JosephMiller yeah, sorry about that. If I work out a fix I'll let you know. You can detect long pasting strings (eg more than 4 characters) by chancing this line `if(dif > 1)` to `if(dif > 4)`

Comment: @NickParsons i have a new issue, am not sure how this works, but download this spam bot software ( https://www.garyshood.com/rsclient/ ) and use the auto typer and test it in here https://www.tamil2friends.com/paste/, events are not detected :( need help

Comment: @JosephMiller I think your software isn't pasting the text, but rather is typing out every letter in the textbox (like a human would), thus there is no past event